# error launching studio when run an apk on android studio

Tags: android-studio

i'm quite new to the android world and have recently encountered an issue. While trying to launch an apk i found online, i stumble across an error message i do not fully understand. it mentions that i'm running a 32 bit executable. I have already checked that the JDK installed is 64 bit and that i have studio 64 installed and not studio. Also, i'm pretty sure i have set the environment variables correctly. So if any of you guys could answer my query, it'd be great thank you !

[image: error message that pops up]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Android Studio is not x86_64? Try to download and install the 64 bit (`android-studio-ide-173.4819257-windows.exe`) from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads , instead of 32-bit version.